# How to create image from text strings

Tags: c#, graphics, ocr

I perform a screen capture and get an image with a text in it. Let consider the text in the image to read - 'Hello'.

Now, I would like to 'create' an image from text 'Hello' which has all the same properties (font style, size, pixel format..) as the text - Hello from my captured image.

I'm using the following code to convert the string - Hello to an image.

```
string str = "Hello";
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(74, 16, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
  using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp))
  {
    Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 11, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 74, 16);
    gfx.DrawString(str, font, new SolidBrush(Color.White), 1, 1);
    bmp.Save(@"C:\temp\" + str + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
  }
```

The two images (one from screen capture, and second from creating) are not the same.

How do I create an image with text which would match exactly to the image with text from the screen capture ?

Here is the code I use to screen capture from the third party application....

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(194, 41, 74, 16);

        using (Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height))
        {
          using (Graphics gfxScreenShot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenShot))
          {
            gfxScreenShot.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmpScreenShot.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gfxScreenShot.Dispose();


            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            bmpScreenShot.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            bmpScreenShot.Save(@"c:\temp\pic1_0.bmp");
          }
     }
```

Comment: when you say the images are not the same, what exactly do you mean? can you post the images? Are you using the same Font? How do you know what font it was and what font style was used? Did the application that generated the initial image have any kind of advanced text formatting capabilities such as advanced font kerning settings?

Comment: I'm basically doing a screen capture of a third party application screen. I don't know what font was used in the screen capture image.

Comment: If you don't know what font was used (and as such, neither the size and style) then how do you expect the images to be the same?

Comment: I have pasted the snap shot of the code I use to screen capture from the third party application.

Comment: Is there a way for me to infer the font style and rest of the properties from the screen captured image and use the properties to create the image from the text ?

Comment: I have been at this project for last two to three days with no luck. Kindly help.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your ultimate goal really is but what you need to look into is an OCR application that can identify fonts. Then you have the problem of determining the size of the font and the style (regular, italic, oblique, bold etc.).

Comment: Appreciate the respose Miky. Will explore OCR application

Comment: There are online apps that can identify fonts for you, given an image.  Try http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: Are you only interested in the text and the style of the text the third party application is displaying? Or do you have to reproduce also the background and window style in your image?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to implement an OCR. I've never tried anything like it, and can imagine it get's quite complicated. You might want to check out other (open-source) OCRs, like:

- [OCR in the Cloud](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/services/), by Microsoft
- [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

Comment: Tessnet2 looks pretty cool! Do you know if it does Font family & style recognition as well or is it strictly for converting image to text?

Comment: Tesseract, which Tessnet2 is a .NET wrapper of, only produces plain text.